# Rails - PDFkit not working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, asset-pipeline, pdfkit

Im working on deploying my rails application on an Ubuntu server with Apache2 and Passenger.

So far everything is up and running smoothly except for one issue.

Part of my app involves generating pdf's from html web pages.

Im using pdfkit to do this.

```
gem 'pdfkit'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
```

I could not find the instructions I followed for getting pdf kit up and working, when I was running the application on my localhost.

But this is a good example: https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit

The issue Im having is I believe pdfkit is not getting precompiled with my assets.

Inside `application.rb` i have:

```
require 'pdfkit'
module RailsPdf
  class Application < Rails::Application
      config.middleware.use PDFKit::Middleware
  end
end
```

Inside my `config/initializers/assets.rb` I had

```
ActionController::Base.asset_host = Proc.new { |source, request|
  if request.env["REQUEST_PATH"].include? ".pdf"
    "file://#{Rails.root.join('public')}"
  else
    "#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}"
  end
}
```

I could not find where I got this from or why it is there. But it was giving me an issue on the line `if request.env["REQUEST_PATH"].include? ".pdf"` 
[image]

I could not get my application index page to load at all until I got rid of that code. I have since seen an example here: https://gist.github.com/francescognarra/9665736

And replaced the above code with the following:

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.root_url = "file://#{Rails.root.join('public')}/"
end
```

I can now start the application and browse all my pages. But, I cannot create a new pdf or view any previously generated ones. If I try to I get the following error log that I do not understand.

[image]

Does anyone have some strong experience using PDFkit with rails in production? 
And can help confirm for me my belief that the issue lies with PDFkit not getting precompiled properly?

Answer (score 1):

I found where my original code inside assets.rb was coming from.

I got the code from here: http://jguimont.com/post/2627758108/pdfkit-and-its-middleware-on-heroku

I put it there due to an issue with pdfkit hanging forever when trying to generate a pdf.

The code I have since replaced it with:

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|
  config.root_url = "file://#{Rails.root.join('public')}/"
end
```

Is working just fine.

Im still not sure what that error was in the last picture I posted.

I tried to generate another pdf to see the error again and got a clear error of:

```
PDFKit::NoExecutableError (No wkhtmltopdf executable found at /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
>> Please install wkhtmltopdf - https://github.com/pdfkit/PDFKit/wiki/Installing-WKHTMLTOPDF):
```

I followed these commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ecometrica/servers
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

But that did not solve the issue. So I saw another post that said to do `gem install wkhtmltopdf-binary` which is what finally solved the issue.

Im still unsure why I had to run that command though, even when I have it set to install from my Gemfile.

I hope this helps someone else.